# Table not found exception using javalite

Tags: sql, jdbc, activejdbc, javalite, activeweb

So I have a very simple table I made in SQL using h2

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255),

);
```

I'm trying to use javalite to add an entry to it so I made this following the instructions on the site.

```
package DBTEST;

import org.javalite.activejdbc.Base;

public class makeDB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base.open("org.h2.Driver", "jdbc:h2:./test", "sa", "");

        User e = new User();
        e.set("username", "John");
        e.set("password", "Doe");
        e.saveIt();


        User.findAll().dump();
        Base.close();
    }
}
```

I have a class Users for this table

```
package DBTEST;

import org.javalite.activejdbc.Model;
import org.javalite.activejdbc.annotations.Table;

@Table("USERS")
public class User extends Model {
}
```

I keep getting this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.javalite.activejdbc.DBException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "USERS" not found; SQL statement:
```

Can anyone help? I have no idea why this is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First,  your SQL has an extra comma in "CREATE USERS" statement. The errors says: "able "USERS" not found" - this mean you simply do not have a table!
- Second, the table definition is missing an `id`, please see https://javalite.io/surrogate_primary_keys
- Third, I created a simple example project and added your  code there. It is working as expected. The project can be found here: https://github.com/javalite/h2-example

The output from running this program looks like this:

```
Model: activejdbc.examples.simple.User, table: 'users', attributes: {ID=1, PASSWORD=Doe, USERNAME=John}
```

which is exactly as expected.

Additionally, the `@Table` annotation is not necessary: https://javalite.io/english_inflections